# Apache Reverse Proxy - Error reading from remote server

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I have a machine that is serving to localhost:8000, I want to reverse proxy this with apache.

I have set up `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass / http://real_address.net/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/

</VirtualHost>
```

(nb real_address is my actual domain not actually real_address) 
When I attempt to go my domain it does not work. I get 502. Error reading from remote server.

What am I doing wrong?

The modules I have:

```
ore_module (static)
so_module (static)
watchdog_module (static)
http_module (static)
log_config_module (static)
logio_module (static)
version_module (static)
unixd_module (static)
access_compat_module (shared)
alias_module (shared)
auth_basic_module (shared)
authn_core_module (shared)
authn_file_module (shared)
authz_core_module (shared)
authz_host_module (shared)
authz_user_module (shared)
autoindex_module (shared)
deflate_module (shared)
dir_module (shared)
env_module (shared)
filter_module (shared)
headers_module (shared)
mime_module (shared)
mpm_event_module (shared)
negotiation_module (shared)
proxy_module (shared)
proxy_ajp_module (shared)
proxy_balancer_module (shared)
proxy_connect_module (shared)
proxy_html_module (shared)
proxy_http_module (shared)
rewrite_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

Comment: From one hand you say that your remote server is `real_address.net` but from the other you return a different location header : `localhost:8000`. 
I would suggest `ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/ ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/`

Comment: I am trying to set it up so that I can access my site from the internet using my domain name. So that needs to be connected to my localhost:8000 ?